# How to print to the same file from different PARFOR iterations?

Tags: matlab, file, parfor

Consider the following pair of functions:

```
function fileTop
test = fopen('test.txt','w');
fprintf(test,'In function "fileTop"\r\n');
fileMid(test)
fprintf(test,'Back in function "fileTop"');
fclose(test);
end
```

and:

```
function fileMid(fid)
for k = 1:5
    pause(rand)
    fprintf(test,'In "fileMid %d" at %f\r\n',k,now);
end
end
```

If you just run `fileTop` you get a new text file (in case it's the first time) with the following content:

```
In function "fileTop"
In "fileMid 1" at 736847.920072
In "fileMid 2" at 736847.920073
In "fileMid 3" at 736847.920081
In "fileMid 4" at 736847.920087
In "fileMid 5" at 736847.920096
Back in function "fileTop"
```

which is just fine!

Now, try to change the loop in `fileMid` to `parfor`, and you get an error:

> Error using fileMid (line 2)
>   Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Is there a way to solve this?

BTW, I don't care for the order in which the iterations are printed.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally unwise to have multiple processes modifying the same resource. If the two processes happen to write to the file at the exact same time you could end up with their outputs being interleaved or overwriting one another.

A better idea would be to have each worker output to its own unique file, such as the file name plus some identifier unique to the worker. This identifier could be gotten from [`labindex`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/labindex.html) when using [`spmd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/execute-simultaneously-on-multiple-data-sets.html):

```
[filePath, fileName, fileExt] = fileparts(file_name);
workerFile = fullfile(filePath, [file_name '_' int2str(labindex) fileExt]);
```

or from the [current task object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/getcurrenttask.html) when using [`parfor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html):

```
[filePath, fileName, fileExt] = fileparts(file_name);
task = getCurrentTask;
workerFile = fullfile(filePath, [file_name '_' int2str(task.ID) fileExt]);
```

Then, once the workers have completed, have the master process collect the individual data files into a single file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code above is that after the first access to the file, I'm trying to pass it's `fid` to the workers, but they can't connect with the main program, and so they find the file with `fid` as inaccessible.

The way to solve this, **albeit I'm not sure if it's recommended**, is to pass the file name itself to the workers, and open and close the file in every worker. This is how `fileTop` look like after the change:

```
function fileTop
file_name = 'test.txt';
test = fopen(file_name,'w');
fprintf(test,'In function "fileTop"\r\n');
fclose(test);
parfor k = 1:5
    fileMid(test,k)
end
test = fopen(file_name,'a');
fprintf(test,'Back in function "fileTop"');
fclose(test);
end
```

And this is `fileMid`:

```
function fileMid(file_name,k)
test = fopen(file_name,'a');
pause(rand)
fprintf(test,'In "fileMid %d" at %f\r\n',k,now);
fclose(test);
end
```

And a possible output would be:

```
In function "fileTop"
In "fileMid 2" at 736847.917401
In "fileMid 4" at 736847.917404
In "fileMid 3" at 736847.917405
In "fileMid 1" at 736847.917409
In "fileMid 5" at 736847.917410
Back in function "fileTop"
```

Comment: It is likely that the worker threads here will overwrite each other’s output, if they’re allowed to write to the same file. Maybe this depends on the OS.

Comment: They don't overwrite, they just append the lines in an unpredictable order, which is not a problem in my case. If two processes will end in the exact same fraction of a second you may be right, but I have not encountered such a situation. I do agree, though, that this is not the best practice.